# Sign in to web application with Microsoft

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, next-auth

I have a nextjs app that allows users to sign in with Microsoft (using nextauth). I registered the app in AzureAD and everything works alright. But if I try to with any Microsoft account which is not registered in my organization, I get this error:

> AADSTS50020: User account 'myemail@email.com' from identity provider
> 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'orgdomain.com' and cannot access
> the application 'at0293-9999-999c-9999c-99999c9a299'(MyAppName) in
> that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the
> tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active
> Directory user account.

I want any Microsoft account to have access to the app. They don't have to be in my organization. I have set the supported account types to "**All Microsoft Account User**" but that didn't fix it. I still have to explicitly add accounts to my organization before they can sign in.
Is there any way around this?

[image: Supported account types settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: To authenticate multi-tenant users and the Microsoft account users, you have to create Azure Ad application by selecting "*Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID
> tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)*" option and the **Sign-in URL** must be
> **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/`** Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#authority).

I registered a **multi-tenant** application:

[image]

For ***sample***, to authorize users I used below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read 
&state=12345
```

When **I tried to sign-in as Microsoft account user, I got the same error** as below:

[image]

**To resolve the error, pass **`common`** authorize endpoint**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read 
&state=12345
```

***The Microsoft account user signed-in successfully:***

[image]

[image]

Pass **common** as the value for `tenantid` in your code:

```js
AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID=ClientID 
AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET=ClientSecret 
AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID=common
```

**Reference:**

[Error AADSTS50020 - User account from identity provider does not exist in tenant - Active Directory |](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist)